# Postgresql money (or numeric?) type and its corresponding type in Scala (Java)

Tags: java, postgresql, scala, playframework-2.2, anorm

I have a project in `Scala` which uses `Postresql`. It involves the type money of Postresql. I did a research and found that I should avoid using `money` data type in Postgresql and better use `NUMERIC`.

Also I'm using `BigDecimal` at client (in Scala). But I can't make it work due to error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter extractor: anorm.Column[BigDecimal]
[error]     SqlParser.get[BigDecimal]("due_price") ~
```

So the questions are:

1. What datatypes should I use in both `Play` and `Postgresql`?
2. If one of them is `BigDecimal`, how do I get rid of the error?

P.S. I'm aware about `java.util.Currency`, but I don't need it, I only need an **amount** of money which is should be `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BigDecimal but the problem here is that BigDecimal type you are getting from Anorm is java.math.BigDecimal while in your case classes you are actually using scala.math.BigDecimal.

To make it work you can either:

1) Define your case classes with java.math.BigDecimal and use this type in your application.

OR

2) Convert between these two in your parser and keep the scala types in your application. This seems to be a better solution. We have used this approach in production. Example:

```
case class ABC (id: Int, price: BigDecimal, decimalPlaces: Int)
```

You parser will look like:

```
val simple = {
  get[Int]("id") ~ get[java.math.BigDecimal]("price") ~ get[Int]("decimalPlaces") map {
  case id ~ price ~ decimalPlaces  => ABC(id, BigDecimal(price), decimalPlaces)
}
```

And when you need to convert from Scala BigDecimal back to Java BigDecimal (for insert, update etc):

```
val priceAsJavaBD = priceAsScalaBD.bigDecimal //Returns java.math.BigDecimal
```

Also, you can have a field (e.g. decimalPlaces) to explicitly define how many decimal places you want when showing this price.

Comment: what about the troubles I might face with using BigDecimal? What are id and decimalPlaces?

Comment: What troubles you expect? We have been using this for all our money-related types and it works fine. Id and decimalPlaces are just examples of other fields that your case class might have, you can remove them. Optionally you can use decimalPlaces, to explicitly define the rounding you expect: for example if you have 13.45217676 as price and your decimalPlaces is 3, you know you have to round it to 13.452.

Comment: @Alex If you use multiple currencies, different currencies might have different decimal places needs. Have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

Comment: By troubles I mean the ones Aleksey Izmailov mean.

Comment: @Alex It's a matter of preference. Aleksey Izmailov suggestion works as well especially when you have only one single currency or all your currencies have the same decimal places requirement.  For crypto-currencies, you can add your codes :-).

Comment: 1) Should the type of postgresql be NUMERIC? 2) Why not to use java.util.Currency instead of ABC?

Comment: @Alex 1) Yes. 2) These are 2 different things. ABC is a sample case class of your application which you want to have due_price for. You also can find Scala Currency implementations if you want:  http://www.thomasknierim.com/114/scala/scala-currency-class/. And you wrote in your question "I'm aware about java.util.Currency, but I don't need it"

Comment: Alright. But if I decide to use `scala-currency-class`, what's the data type should I use in Postgresql and at a client (to parse what comes from db)? I could use Numeric, but `scala-currency-class` doesn't have apply method getting `java.math.BigDecimal` and I have to use `.toString` each time. Isn't there other, more sensible way?

Comment: @Alex I've never used Scala Currency. But the solution remains the same. In your db, you have to store as Numeric and as soon as you retrieve the results in your application (through Anorm etc), you can convert from Java BigDecimal to Scala BigDecimal so you can easily use it anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite common to use integer types to store money in cents to avoid rounding errors and penny shaving. You can use Int, Long, BigInt - whatever you prefer.

Comment: Wouldn't I be better off using BigDecimal?

Comment: I guess to avoid overflows and such it would be a good idea to use `BigInt`. Scalas `BigInt` has the same range of values aka precision as Postgres `bigint`. BigDecimal still lets you get into trouble :)

Comment: the error about `could not find implicit value for parameter extractor` persists but for BigInt now.

Answer (score 0):

Your Anorm version doesn't provide Column[BigInt] extractor. Either you can upgrade it to master, or you copy actual Column definition from master (Column.scala) to your project so it's available at compile time.